# Sind Fragen zur Wortbedeutung on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, allowed-questions

Mich würde die Bedeutung des Wortes "knietschig" interessieren, dabei interessiert mich:

1. Woher die Bedeutung im Sinne von matschig kommt?
2. Was jemand mit dem Wort verbindet?

Nun ist die Fragestellung zu 2. natürlich sehr breit und opinion based, wie soll ich nun diese Frage nach dem Wort am besten formulieren, bzw. so fokussieren, daß sie nicht ausartet? Es könnte wohl eher eine Umfrage sein? Dennoch interessiert mich sehr, was man damit verbindet? Ist das dann hier überhaupt on-topic? Wie könnte man das am besten eingrenzen dann?

Answer (score 3):

Fragen zur [Etymologie](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) sind grundsätzlich on Topic, wie auch Fragen zur Bedeutung eines Wortes im Kontext. Es gelten hier die gleichen [Empfehlungen wie zu anderen Fragen](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-about-meaning-translations-or-difference).

Sollten Kommentare darauf hinweisen, die Frage einzugrenzen, oder sollten Fragen zu noch fehlenden Details aufkommen, empfiehlt es sich, diese zeitnah zu beantworten.

Fragen nach der Form einer Frage kann man auch gerne [in unserem Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/deutschsprachiger-raum) stellen.