# Können wir Fragen offen lassen, wenn ein Wörterbuch auch nicht helfen würde?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, vote-to-close

Ich finde jeden Tag Fragen mit Close-Votes, in denen nach dem Bedeutungsnterschied zwischen zwei Wörtern mit ähnlicher Bedeutung gefragt wird, etwa [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50737/difference-between-schicken-abschicken-and-zuschicken-similar-verbs). Die Close-Reason ist:

> This site is about the usage and rules of the German language. It is not well-suited to replace a **dictionary**, **thesaurus**, or **conjugation table**.

Aber hier sind die Bedeutungen so ähnlich, dass ein Blick ins Wörterbuch auch nicht weiterhilft. Wenn wir finden, dass das zu wenig eigenständiger Forschungsaufwand war, weil keine Wörterbücher zitiert werden, machen wir Fragestellern das Leben auch nur schwerer, ohne dass wir erwarten können, dass die Fragequalität dadurch steigt.

Können wir solche Fragen also einfach offen lassen?

Answer (score 4):

Ja, können wir. Dies ist ziemlich genau das, was ich mit [diesem Vorstoß](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/2594) angestrebt habe (der angenommen wurde). Siehe auch: [Wann soll ich welchen Schließgrund bei Fragen nach Übersetzungen, Bedeutungen u. Ä. verwenden?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1103/2594)

Was das Schließen solcher Fragen betrifft, gibt es folgende Phänomene zu berücksichtigen:

1. Nutzer stimmen dafür, Fragen zu schließen, weil sie denken, dass alle Fragen ohne Dokumentation der eigenen Recherche geschlossen werden müssen – weil der Schließgrund dies nahelegt. Man könnte dies durch einen geschickt formulierten Schließgrund vermeiden (z. B. »It seems that this question can be answered by …«), was auch damals zur Erwägung stand, aber vorwiegend aus Platzgründen usw. nicht passiert ist.
2. Muttersprachler überschätzen, was Wörterbücher zu leisten vermögen, oder scheitern anderweitig daran, sich in die Perspektive eines Sprachlerners zu versetzen.
3. Andere Nutzer unterschätzen Wörterbücher.

Dass es zu unterschiedlichen Meinungen wegen Punkt 2 und 3 kommt, ist unvermeidbar, aber auch kein großartiges Problem, da das Schließen einer Frage das Ergebnis einer Abstimmung ist (es sei denn, ein Moderator hat seine Finger im Spiel). So wurde auch die Beispielfrage eben nicht geschlossen, da [Reviewer (einstimmig) so votiert haben](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/close/25115).

Punkt 1 ist ein Problem und kann am besten vermieden werden, in dem die betroffenen Nutzer informiert werden. Wenn Du also siehst, dass eine solche Frage durch Schließung bedroht ist, hinterlasse ruhig einen Kommentar, der dagegen argumentiert. Beachte allerdings, dass Du in den meisten Fällen nicht zwischen Punkt 1 und 2 unterscheiden kannst, und daher beide Fälle in Deinem Kommentar abdecken solltest. Beispielsweise kannst Du kommentieren, dass Du denkst, dass auch ein Wörterbuch nicht helfen würde und dass die Frage dementsprechend nicht geschlossen werden muss, mit Verweis auf [diese FAQ](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1103/2594).

Comment: Nur zur Klarstellung: Mein Eindruck (aus anderen SEs, nehme ich an) war immer, dass man die Diskussion über Schließen/Öffnen einer Frage nicht in Kommentaren unter der Frage führen soll, sondern im jeweiligen Meta. Habe ich mich da getäuscht?

Comment: @sgf: Wenn es in eine echte Diskussion ausartet, ja. Wenn es bei ein paar Kommentaren bleibt, ist das meines Erachtens völlig unpraktikabel. Ein einzelner Kommentar, warum eine Frage geschlossen werden sollte oder nicht, ist absolut in Ordnung.

Answer (score 1):

Es gibt mehr als ein Wörterbuch, also welche Wörterbücher wurden konsultiert? Diese sollten nicht nur genannt, sondern nach Möglichkeit verlinkt werden, so dass nicht jeder Helfer selbst suchen muss und zitieren und so dass man weiß, was der Stand ist, von dem der Frager ausgeht.

Wenn in den Wörterbüchern Unterschiede gezeigt werden, so sollte erklärt werden, wieso diese dem Frager nicht genügen. Es soll nicht in ein Ratespiel ausarten.